# viewing .cxx files in Doxygen documentation along with .h files

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm trying to create Doxygen documentation for a C++ code package. When viewing the HTML documentation generated, I can view the header files for the package but cannot view the .cxx files, although the .cxx files are being detected by Doxygen. Could you advise me on how I would be able to include the .cxx files for viewing in the HTML documentation?

Preemptive thanks

Comment: Do you want to see the analysis of the .cxx files, the filenames or the contents of the files?  Have you reviewed your Doxygen setup (using the advanced tab)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the SOURCE_BROWSER variable and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Setting SOURCE_BROWSER to YES fixed it. Thank you very much for your assistance.

I award you 10 internet points.